# Critical hit with Acid Splash: how much damage?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, cantrips, critical-hit

[Telekinetic Projectile](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=334) does list that it does double damage on a critical hit.

Compare this to [Acid Splash](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=3):

> On a critical success, the target **also** takes 1 persistent acid damage.

Should this "also" mean that *beside* the usual damage doubling? Or a critical is just normal damage + 1 persistent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Normal +1 persistent

Acid Splash involves an attack roll but is [not a Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=222) and does not benefit from automatic double damage.

> If you **critically succeed at a Strike**, your attack deals double damage. **Other attacks, such as spell attack rolls** and some uses of the Athletics skill, describe the specific effects that occur when their outcomes are critical successes.

Acid Splash specifies

> If you hit, you deal 1d6 acid damage plus 1 splash acid damage. On a critical success, the target also takes 1 persistent acid damage.

The persistent is in addition to its normal damage, not any other bonus.